# Jquery Find a specific class with a specific attribute value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I currently have something like this in my code

```
<input class="parameterValueInput" trigger="@item.Name">
```

What I would like to do is to change content of an input that has a class name `parameterValueInput` and attribute called `trigger` with value "triggerValue";
I am not sure how to write a selector for that. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this :

```js
$("input[class=parameterValueInput][trigger=triggerValue]").focus()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="parameterValueInput" trigger="triggerValdue">
<input class="parameterValueInput" trigger="triggerValu2e">
<input class="parameterValueInput" trigger="triggerValue">
```

As , @mplungjan said in comment to use `$("input.parameterValueInput[trigger=triggerValue]")` if you have mutliple class else if only one class use above .

Comment: `$("input.parameterValueInput[trigger=triggerValue]")` is likely more safe

Comment: Your selector will fail on `<input class="parameter parameterValueInput" `

Comment: @mplungjan yes you are right :) Thank you for suggestion  . I have added your suggestion in my answer .

Comment: ALWAYS use .class EVEN if you have one class, since it takes only a second to add a class and break the script. That can be added even from another part of the script so NEVER use class=someClass over .someClass